# android Setonclicklistener doesn't work with menu's items

Tags: android

i have a menu that contains just one item.

```
Button exit;
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
        blowUp.inflate(R.menu.exitmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }
exit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bexitMenuExit);
```

if i add listener to exit button , i got excpetion (null pointer), i am sure that there is no syntax error, the button exit is comming from this menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/bexitMenuExit"
        android:title="Exit"


        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
        ></item>
</menu>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to initialize `Button` and this doesn't make sence for me.
Just inflate your `Menu` and just *override onOptionsItemSelected* method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   new MenuInflater(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.menu.exitmenu, menu);
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch(item.getId()) {
      case R.id.bexitMenuExit:
         // work that will start when you click on this
      ...
   }
}
```

Also, there is no need to use `OnClickListener`, for this there is `onOptionsItemSelected` method and you should use it.

Comment: so for what you using MenuInflater? for create Menu, isn't?

Comment: so do it like is it in my answer.

Comment: i will give print screen wait please

Comment: i don't know what is not clear. just inflate menu with XML resource as i meant and then override onOptionsItemSelected method and it's all.

Comment: i understand that you are talking about list of items(menu) , but i am talking about menu that appear on clicking menu (sorry my english is bad to descript) see the photo please

Comment: so when you click on Menu button, options menu will be shown.

Comment: yes i know that, and in the menu there is button exit ,i want to set onclicklistener to it

Comment: Did you read my answer? there is no need to OnClickListener, Alternative for this is overriden method onOptionsItemSelected, check my answer again. when you click on your exit in menu, this method will be called and you should use this method, always.

Answer (score 0):

for menu items, as stated by Sajmon, you can use onOptionsIemsSelected function. onClickListener is used by views while this function has been designed to be used specifically by menu items using switch case.